# What are the condition for the elements of diagonal of matrix to be eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we a have a  operator  $A$ and let $e_i$ be a basis formed by eigenvectors of $A$.
Now suppose that $E$ is the matrix representation of $A$ in the basis $e_i$ and suppose also that $E$ is diagonal.
In order to the the elements of the diagonal of $E$ to be eigenvalues of $A$ should  $e_i$ be orthonormal?

Comment: Firstly, the eigenvectors $\{e_i\}$ of $A$ might not form a basis. In the event that they do form a basis and $E$ is diagonal, then the elements on the diagonal are necessarily the eigenvalues since  $E e_i = E_{ii} e_i$ (no summation)

Comment: @AlkaKadri remember that if $e_i$ is an eigenvector thant $ke_i$ is an egeinvector where $k$ is a real number.So I think that $e_i$ should be orthonormal

Comment: @amiltonmoreira What does the first sentence of your comment have to do with the second?

Comment: @amilton The answer is no: if a basis can be formed from the eigenvectors of $A$, then it is necessarily true that the matrix representation of $A$ relative to this basis is diagonal.

Comment: The diagonal elements are necessarily the eigenvalues, but the eigenvectors are not necessarily orthonormal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, but I know why you asked. I think your confusion comes because you are thinking about the setting of Hilbert spaces, where you essentially have two different ways of defining $E$.

---

In linear algebra, **the matrix $E$ representing an operator $A$ in a basis $(e_i)_i$** is the matrix with elements $E_{ij}$ defined by
$$ A e_i=\sum_{j} E_{ji}e_j. $$
If $E$ is diagonal, then this reduces to
$$ A e_i= E_{ii} e_i \qquad \forall i, $$
so the diagonal elements are eigenvalues of $A$. This is always true even if you work in a space without an inner product

---

Now, if the space has an inner product, you can define a **second** matrix from $A$:
$$ B_{ij}:=\langle{e_i,Ae_j}\rangle. $$
Now, **if the basis $(e_i)_i$ is orthonormal**, you can show that
$$ E_{ij}=B_{ij}\quad\forall i,j. $$
The last identity fails in general, i.e. $E\neq B$, if the basis is not orthonormal. Moreover, **if the basis is not orthonormal, the matrix $B$ does not necessarily contain eigenvalues as diagonal entries when diagonal**, despite $E$ doing so. This is the whole point.

This simply means that you cannot define $E$ as the matrix $B$ in general. $E$ and $B$ are two different things: the first is the matrix representation of $A$, the second is a useful expression that just happens to be equal to $E$ when the basis is orthonormal. The matrix $B$ is not what you should call “the matrix representation of $A$ in basis $(e_i)_i$” if the basis is not orthonormal.